# Passing a function that accepts any number and type of arguments as a class template argument

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I am aware that functions can be template arguments. However GCC, Clang and MSVC (compile versions on [rextester](http://rextester.com/LMQPG90119)) do not compile compile when the template is variadic, as shown below:

```
void Func( int ){}

template<void (*)(int)>
struct Foo{};

template struct Foo<Func>; // Compiles

template<typename>
struct Bar;

template<typename ...Args>
struct Bar<void(*)(Args...)>
{
};

template struct Bar<Func>; // Does NOT compile (why???)

int main()
{
}
```

MSVC produces the most verbose output and possible explanation (rightly or wrongly) as to why the code does not compile.

```
source_file.cpp(20): error C2923: 'Bar': 'Func' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'T'
source_file.cpp(1): note: see declaration of 'Func'
source_file.cpp(20): error C2990: 'Bar': non-class template has already been declared as a class template
source_file.cpp(13): note: see declaration of 'Bar'
source_file.cpp(20): error C2946: explicit instantiation; 'Bar' is not a template-class specialization
```

What is the appropriate syntax for passing functions that accept any number of arguments themselves as class template arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Func` is not a type, but a function,

you might want:

```
template struct Bar<decltype(&Func)>;
```

or maybe

```
template<typename F, F f> struct Bar;

template <typename ...Args, void(*f)(Args...)>
struct Bar<void(*)(Args...), f>
{
};
```

and `Bar<decltype(&Func), &Func>`.

Which can be simplified to (since C++17):

```
template <auto> struct Bar;

template <typename ...Args, void(*f)(Args...)>
struct Bar<f>
{
};
```

and `Bar<&Func>`.

Comment: That was my original solution. I just wondered why `template struct Foo<Func>;` compiles.

Comment: @Olumide because `Foo` takes a non-type parameter (of type `void (*)(int)`)

Comment: @user463035818 Thanks. BTW, I don't even think my specialization of `Bar` is a match for `template struct Bar<decltype(&Func)>`, at least not on GCC and Clang because they complain that `template 'Bar<decltype(Func)>` is undefined.

Comment: @Jarod42  Which compiler did you use. The C++17 and C++17 versions of updated answer do not compile on GCC 7.3.0.

Comment: @Olumide: Compile fine [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4856f7e0aae8b068) with both clang version 5.0.0-3~16.04.1 and g++ (GCC) 8.1.0.

Comment: @Jarod42 out of curiosity why is is `typename ...Args` allowed to appear before `void(*f)(Args...)` in the specialization bearing in mind this: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/temp.class.spec#8.6

Comment: @Olumide: As I read it, it is in `struct Bar<VariadicShouldBeLast...>` not in `template </**/>` that applies.

Comment: @Olumide: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52175224/how-can-a-template-parameter-pack-have-other-trailing-arguments